# Adding more controls to RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: asp.net, validation

Is there a way to add more than one `ControlToValidate` to my RegularExpressionValidator?

I have two textboxes for postcode and I want to add the same RegularExpressionValidator to both.

Currently I have one for each box but if they are both wrong it shows up two error messages but I only want the user to see one.

Here's my RegularExpressionValidator

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="errorpopup" Display="Dynamic" ID="rvpPostCodeZone" validationgroup="tbEditEmailCorr" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<strong>Please enter a valid post code.</strong>" ControlToValidate="tbEditPostCodeZone"  ValidationExpression="^[0-9a-zA-Z' ']{3,}$" SetFocusOnError="true" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CustomValidator`, and perform the regex match server-side (and also on the client-side as well if you want). In the validation function(s) for this validator, check both controls.

Comment: I ended up using some jQuery to insert the text from both textboxes into a separate hidden one and then validating that